# Unable to satisfy requirements when specifying version in podfile

Tags: cocoapods

I'm using the Cocoapods app. When trying to install the current Alamofire, I get the following error:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Alamofire (~> 4.4)` required by `Podfile`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Alamofire (~> 4.4)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default
```

This is my podfile:

```
project 'MyApp.xcodeproj'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'

end
```

If I remove the version and just use `pod 'Alamofire'`, it installs version 4.0.1. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is as per the last line of the log.

You need to run `pod repo update`

There appears to be an option in the app in the menu Specs Repos that has an update button for me. However this does not seem to work.

Running the command line then allowed mre to run Build->Install from the Cocoapods app

Answer (score -1):

This might be happening due to the cocoa pod version required by the new almofire version is higher than what u have installed in your system. Please  check version of ypu pod by pod --version in command line , if it is less than 1.0 update pod spec , you can find the steps here .https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html
Your new pod will be installed. Also the when u don not specify a version in your pod file than cocoa pods itself selects the latest version it supports and install it .Thats why your almofire was getting updated to 4.0.1.,Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that earlier. It's 1.2 both when I check the Cocoapods app and in terminal.